# Using System.Runtime.Caching, But When I Go To Retrieve it, it's null?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caching

I've got a C# WPF application and I'm trying to implement Caching using the new System.Runtime.Caching.  When I add something to the Cache, I then check it and confirm it is there, which it is.  However, when I restart the application, it is gone from the Cache.

So, in the below example, the output will always be "Found It".  What I expect it to be is that the first time it is run it outputs "Found It", but all subsequent times (for the next 10 days) it would output "Was already present", but it doesn't.  I've run it through the debugger and confirmed that every time you restart the application, cache["MYDATA"] will equal null.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>> _CachedObjects = null;
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

_CachedObjects = cache["MYDATA"] as Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>>;
if (_CachedObjects == null)
{
     _CachedObjects = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>>();

    //code that fills _CachedObjects

     CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
     policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(10.0);

     cache.Set("MYDATA", _CachedObjects, policy);

     if(cache["MYDATA"] != null)
          Console.WriteLine("Found It");
}
else
     Console.WriteLine("Was already present");
```

Comment: Isn't that by Design? I mean, if you restart the application the Cache is cleared. For that you might want to use an external cache source.

Comment: If that's the case, what advantage would the cache offer me over a static property then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MemoryCache` object is maintained in volatile memory so you will need to extend `ObjectCache` object to store in the file system or some other non-volatile storage mechanism.

Comment: I don't get it then.  What's the point of Caching it?  I can just store it in a variable and get the same effect, no?  Actually, in my above example, _CachedObjects is currently a static property of a static class that I was using globally in the application.  I was trying to optimize performance by storing it's contents so it didn't have to be reloaded.  What's the point of converting it to the ObjectCache though if it's lost?

Comment: The point is that if you retrieve something from cache it's faster than getting it off the disk or a web service.  So when you app starts up you cache things and then serve them from cache.  Thats why a lot of server apps take a while to come online, because they are caching many things eagerly to improve the performance of the app in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, but how does that beat storing it in a property?  Is it the case that anything stored in cache doesn't consume memory in your application?  Otherwise, I can't think of any reason why it would make sense to use cache over variables/properties.

Comment: @Nullqwerty - The usefulness really shows with the options available on the `CacheItemPolicy` object. For example, you can set a sliding expiration `TimeSpan` that will cause the item to be removed if it is not used in a certain amount of time.

Comment: ahhh....ok.  Too bad...persistent cache would have been really nice.  Oh well.  Thanks!